# How can I romance Samantha Traynor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

That Traynor girl is fine. I'd like to check a private message from her console... If you know what I'm saying.

Is it possible to romance her? If yes, how?

Is it possible if I'm a Femshep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have a relationship with her if your character is a lady. You'll need to not be in a relationship when she comes over to your cabin for a game night (you will receive an email) and do the obvious flirting.

Comment: AFAIK, you CAN be in a relationship, but your spouse will know about it. I was engaged with Liara, and she was not happy about it.

Comment: @Sandokan Ye, this usually happens. :D I was wondering whether it is possible to draw even bigger tits to these characters. :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to be a woman but yes, you can. If you do, you'll get a nice little scene for your troubles (but it's short, not like the main character scenes)